# C# inheritance vs. instantiation, what's the major difference and when to use what?

Tags: c#

I've seen some old threads here, but I still can't find a concrete answer as to when to use either the best approach possible.

If you inherit, you get all the properties and methods.
If you instantiate, you get the same.

So is it the accessibility of those properties and methods that rely on either inheritance or instantiation?

Has it something to do with interfaces that a class is implementing, so that a decision is made to  inherit that class, or instantiate?

Please enlighten. Thanks

EDIT:

@Gaz, question regarding your comment below:

```
class ParentClass {}

//why do this to create a child class to inherit the parent's properties and methods...
class ChildClassOne : ParentClass {}

//when you can do this?
var ChildClassOne = new ParentClass();
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect those words don't mean the same to you as they do to me - because I would never consider comparing them. Inheritance is where you declare that one class derives from another, e.g. `class DerivedClass : BaseClass` whereas instantiation is where you create an instance of a class, e.g. `SomeClass x = new SomeClass();` or perhaps `BaseClass x = new DerivedClass();` - they're entirely separate things. Could you clarify your question by providing specific code examples of what you mean?

Comment: (Additionally, are you really interested specifically in C# 4? That's a very old version, and I don't think there's anything specifically about inheritance or instantiation that's changed much since. Perhaps edit the question to just use the C# tag, or clarify why you believe it's specific to C# 4?)

Comment: @jon That C# 4 is the one I found as tag when I type C#, so I clicked it. I understand the syntax of inheritance, and instantiation, but I want to fully understand why do one over the other, when all properties and methods can be used by the child (either derived or instantiated)?

Comment: One is part of a class declaration, another is creating an instance - they're entirely different, so there's no aspect of doing "one over the other". It's like asking whether one should use string concatenation or a `using` directive... they serve *completely* different purposes.

Comment: To put it another way: try to provide two complete programs which *only* differ in terms of whether you declare a derived class or create an instance of a base class. That would be possible if these were really alternatives - but they're not.

Comment: When dealing with classes and inheritance you are dealing with _defining_ the cookie cutter. When dealing with `new` you are actually using the cookie cutter to make cookies. Your question, for a seasoned programmer, is confusing mainly since _defining_ a cookie cutter and _using a cookie cutter_ are such different things that we'd never think to compare them. Fundamentally, defining a cookie cutter doesn't create a cookie - only _using_ it does. You simply can't create a meaningful program _without cutting some cookies_. Alternatively - inheritance is _useful_ but instantiation is _needed_.

Comment: `//why do this to create a child class to inherit the parent's properties and methods...` Now add a property to `ChildClassOne` (but not `ParentClass `). Now show us how to do with _without_ inheritance.

Comment: Let's take a step back. Do you understand that both Rectangle and Circle are both types of Shape? You might say that they _inherit_ from Shape. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @mjwills, I think I understand now. It's not possible to add a few more properties after instantiating and creating the ChildClassOne, like so:  var ChildClassOne = new ParentClass(); ChildClassOne.Phone = 123; ChildClassOne.Height = 60; ... Because it's much more different from Javascript where properties and methods can be added after instantiation. I guess I'm confusing myself with C# that I need to dig deep to understand it's concepts. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, JS is a prototypal language - so the way it does things is quite different.

Comment: Don't forget to vote or accept if you find responses helpful

Answer (score 1):

Further to comments posted, your understanding of the example code is flawed.

```
class ParentClass {}

//why do this to create a child class to inherit the parent's properties and methods...
class ChildClassOne : ParentClass {}

//when you can do this?
var ChildClassOne = new ParentClass();
```

The return type of `new ParentClass();` is an instance of `ParentClass` **not** `ChildClassOne`

Also as you have shown in this line that C# will allow you to name a variable after a class, which adds to the confusion, as you're creating a local scope variable of type `ParentClass` called `ChildClassOne` and assigning it an instance of `ParentClass`. Behind the scenes the `var` type is replaced by `ParentClass`

`ParentClass ChildClassOne = new ParentClass();` might be clearer on that line, but just as confusing in later code.

Inheritance is for use when you may want one or more class types that exhibit common properties and methods e.g.

```
class ChildClassOne : ParentClass
{
  int SomeInt{get;set;} //this doesn't exist in ParentClass
}

class ChildClassTwo : ParentClass
{
  string SomeString{get;set;} //this doesn't exist in ParentClass
}
```

The above are definitions of a class.

Whenever a non-static class is instantiated a new block of memory is allocated for it and it can actually be used in code.

Now you can treat instances both `ChildClassOne` and `ChildClassTwo` as if they were a `ParentClass` e.g.

```
List<ParentClass> listOfClasses = new List<ParentClass>();
listOfClasses.Add(new ParentClass());
listOfClasses.Add(new ChildClassOne());
listOfClasses.Add(new ChildClassTwo());
```

So if `ParentClass` has a method `DoSomething()` that is not given `private` accessibility then you can do:

```
listOfClasses[0].DoSomething();
listOfClasses[1].DoSomething();
listOfClasses[2].DoSomething();
```

but if you wish to access child class properties or methods then you can run into issues.

`var classValue = listOfClasses[0].SomeInt;` will trigger an error at build time as `ParentClass` doesn't have such a property only `ChildClassOne`.

You may try to get passed the build error by casting

`var classValue = ((ChildClassOne)listOfClasses[0]).SomeInt;`

This will get you past the build stage but will trigger an exception at run time.

A real life analogy would be a parking lot.
The parking lot contains many vehicles. Some of the vehicles are SUVs, some are saloons, some are trucks).

Each one is an **instance** of both its type (saloon, truck, pickup, hatchback, SUV) but also its parent type - vehicle.

In this case all vehicles have wheels, but not all vehicles are the same, a truck is not an SUV.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you mean by instantiate,

```
A a = new A();
```

and this is what you mean by inheritance,

```
class B : A
{
   ...
}
```

Then my answer is inherit when writing a class that extends off of the base properties and behavior of the parent class, and instantiate when creating an object of the class for use at runtime.

Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying, but regarding the properties or method, it's the same thing, the child (either instantiated or derived) can use those properties and methods, so is the main purpose of instantiating just to create a new object?

Comment: Instantiation and inheritance are completely different things. Any class must be instantiated before it can be used (statics aside). A derived class must be instantiated too.

Comment: Laila Villa, is your question "Why would anyone want to instantiate a child class instead of a parent class when the child class shares all the same data and methods as the parent class?"

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is just a way of saying "this class contains all the properties and methods of the base class". It's no different from adding

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

which says "this class contains a property called Name".

Inherited or not, all of these properties are available to the code within your class, because the code within your class only becomes viable once your class is instantiated at runtime.

All classes must be instantiated before they can be used (apart from static classes/methods). The code in your class is run in the context of one of those instantiations. Inheritance makes no difference.

Comment: "It's no different from adding [the property]" - it's very, very different IMO. It's not *just* a way of saying "it contains the properties and methods of the base class". It's a way of using an instance of the derived class in code that only knows about the base class, overriding virtual members where appropriate. Your answer severely misrepresents inheritance IMO.

Comment: I totally accept your point, but OP was struggling with the most basic concepts so I was attempting to keep things simple, at least in the context of their question.

Comment: But in doing so you've misrepresented inheritance, as if it were a shortcut for composition. I don't think that will help the OP, either now or in the future. The most important thing for them to understand is that the two concepts they're talking about are not alternatives to each other, and that isn't helped by oversimplifying the meaning of inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

The semantics convey all the differences. There can be several ways in which one class may use other.

#### Inheritance

##### One class derives from another

When you inherit one type from the other, you are saying that the derived type **is** a more specific base type. This would also mean that every derived type is also a base type. A derived type may represent a sub-category of the base type. However, it is also a common practice to use inheritance to add to the functionality of an existing class. However, ideally, inheritance is the right choice when the fundamental relationship between two entities is an **is-a** relationship. (Every `Derived` entity is also a `Base` entity as in every `Employee` is a `Person`)

```
class Person { }
class Employee : Person { }
```

#### Composition and Aggregation

##### When one class contains another

When you declare a entity as an entity in another class as an instance variable, it is called composition.   Composition is, where an entity contains another entity to model membership. Specifically, composition is a **has-a** relationship. For instance, a `Car` may have several `Wheel`s, a `Post` may have `Comment`s.

It is worth noting that there are two variants of composition. An aggregation where the child has a separate existence outside its containing object like an `Engine` can still exist if the `Car` does not exist anymore. However, `Room` cannot exist if a `Building` ceases to exist. This is what is true composition. Mostly, an aggregation means a child can have multiple parents which is not the case with composition.

#### Association

##### One class uses another (as a parameter, return type or local variable)

Composition only applies when a variable is declared as an instance variable. If you have a local instance of one class in one of the methods of the other class or if it returns an object of one class or accepts it as parameter it does not involve composition. This is called an **association**, where a class depends on other classes to fulfill its responsibilities. As an example, a `Passenger` may need  a `Vehicle` to travel:

```
class Passenger
{
    public void Travel(Vehicle v) { }
}
```

Try to model your classes based on the nature of the relationship.
In the end, it is still a matter of opinion of when to use which.

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned composition at all, and I see nothing in their question which suggests they're talking about composition.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for confusing questions, I have so much more of these that i'll try to figure out myself in the coming weeks. cheers

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought since the OP has mentioned instantiation of one class in another, it would be relevant to bring up the semantic aspect of composition and other possible ways (added association now) one class would use an instance of another.

Comment: @AmalK: Where did they say *in another*? If they'd said that, I could understand the thought that this was about composition, but I haven't seen any indication of that. I think the OP is basically a few steps too early in their journey to really consider design implications of inheritance or composition.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree. This may be a bit overwhelming for a beginner. Actually, they didn't say "in another", I assumed it since when we instantiate a class, it has to be in one of the methods of another class/type in C#.